# usage of as and have

Tags: writing-style

When I was reading a novel by Steinbeck, I have met the sentence below:

"He stalked her then, game-wise, as he had the woodchucks on the knoll when day after day he had lain lifeless as a young stone and watched the old wary chucks bring their children out to sun."

I am confused a bit.

Do "...as he had..." mean "... "as if he was watching..."? Would you please explain the grammatical structure in that sentence!

Thanks so much!

Comment: I thought Steinbeck was supposed to be a good writer, but I'm *seriously* unimpressed with that daft metaphor ***lifeless as a young stone***. Even the kind of rocks and stones that geologists call "young" are usually at least *millions* of years old!

Comment: "He stalked her then, game-wise, as he had (stalked)  the woodchucks on the knoll..." The rest is peripheral...

Comment: The precise meaning of that final word ***sun*** seems curiously ambiguous to me. It could be a ***noun*** with the sense of *bringing the chicks out **into the sun** / sunshine / sunlight*, but that would seem a bit clumsy with the specific prepositions he actually used (but noting that "young stone", perhaps Steinbeck was just having a bad day). Alternatively, it's a ***verb*** with the sense of *bringing the chicks out [in order] **to sun themselves / to sunbathe***. Unusually phrased, whichever it is.

Comment: @FF...not sure if Steinbeck is considered a "good" writer...but he was a great  _story teller_. Sometimes there is confusion between the two...

Comment: *He stalked her like he had stalked the woodchucks on the knoll . . .*

Comment: You can consider "**...stalked her...as he had the woochucks...**" to be a slightly shortened version of "**...stalked her _in the same way_ as he had the woodchucks...**".. Does it make sense now?